# Example of a functor which preserves all small limits but has no left adjoint

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

The General Adjoint Functor Theorem (Category Theory) states that for a locally small and complete category $D$, a functor $G\colon D \to C$ has a left adjoint if and only if $G$ preserves all small limits and for each object $A$ in $C$, $A \downarrow G$) has a weakly initial set.

Could someone help by giving an example of a functor $G$ that preserves all small limits but has no left adjoint?

Comment: Let $\emptyset$ be the empty category. Then $G : \emptyset \to \mathcal{C}$ preserves all limits (vacuously), but $G$ has no left adjoint if $\mathcal{C}$ is non-empty.

Comment: @Zhen: but the empty category is not complete.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A nontrivial example is mentioned in MacLane's *Categories for the Working Mathematician* , on page 123: consider the category $\mathbf{CompBool}$ of complete boolean algebras. The forgetful functor $\mathbf{CompBool} \to \mathbf{Set}$ has no left adjoint, but preserves all limits ($\mathbf{CompBool}$ is also small-complete). The reason is that, given a denumerable set $D$, one can construct an arbitrarily large complete Boolean algebra generated by $D$ (a fact that was apparently proved by Solvay in 1966), and so the solution set condition in the General AFT fails.

Comment: For reference, here's the [definition of the solution set condition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/solution+set+condition)

Comment: Also, the solution set condition seems to be a sufficient but not necessary condition for a functor to have a left adjoint, so can that be stated as the reason? Perhaps [this theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem) applies instead? I.e. the property you mention about generating arbitrarily large boolean algebras implies that the forgetful functor is inaccessible?

Answer (score 12):

Martin's answer is probably the one you want, but here's another marginally trivial example.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $\mathbf{1}$ be the terminal category with only one object and one morphism. The unique functor $G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{1}$ obviously preserves all limits, but $G$ has a left adjoint if and only if $\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object. Dually, $G$ preserves all colimits and has a right adjoint if and only if $\mathcal{C}$ has a terminal object.

Comment: Thanks Zhen Lin - your example(s) are very helpful too.

Comment: This example is incomplete; you need to exhibit an example of a category $C$ which is cocomplete but has no terminal object (or dually).

Comment: Berci gives examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980824/example-of-complete-category-with-no-initial-object/ The large posets of sets or ordinals are both cocomplete with no terminal object!